# Sublime insert a symbol to the end of line to make column

Tags: sublimetext

I want to insert **"** to the end of each lines
I have the following text:

```
Some test\n
Also some text\n
The rest of text\n
```

And I want to get like this one:

```
Some test         "\n
Also some text    "\n
The rest of text  "\n
```

Where \n - end of line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a search for "sublime line padding" and found:
http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment

Hope it helps.

**From the website:**

**Features**

Align multiple selections to the same column by inserting spaces (or tabs)

Align all lines in a multi-line selection to the same indent level

Align the first = on each line of a multi-line selection to the same column
See the screenshots below for examples of the plugin in action.

**Installation**
Download Package Control and use the Package Control: Install Package command from the command palette. Using Package Control ensures Alignment will stay up to date automatically.